# Error when Fitting a glmer with poisson error structure

Tags: r

I hope somebody can help me. I'm trying to conduct an analysis which examines the number of samples of Hymenoptera caught over an elevational gradient. I want to examine the possibility of a uni-modal distribution in relation to elevation, as well as a linear distribution. Hence I am including `I(Altitude^2)` as an explanatory variable in the analysis.

I am trying to run the following model which includes a Poisson error structure (as we are dealing with count data) and date and Trap Type (`Trap`) as random effects.

```
model7 <- glmer(No.Specimens~Altitude+I(Altitude^2)+(1|Date)+(1|Trap),
       family="poisson",data=Santa.Lucia,na.action=na.omit)
```

However I keep receiving the following error message:

```
Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
2: In pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tolPwrss, GQmat, compDev, fac, verbose) :
  Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
3: In pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tolPwrss, GQmat, compDev, fac, verbose) :
  Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
```

Clearly I am making some big mistakes. Can anybody help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Here is the structure of the dataframe:

```
str(Santa.Lucia)
'data.frame':   97 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date        : Factor w/ 8 levels "01-Sep-2014",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Trap.No     : Factor w/ 85 levels "N1","N10","N11",..: 23 48 51 14 17 20 24 27 30 33 ...
 $ Altitude    : int  1558 1635 1703 1771 1840 1929 1990 2047 2112 2193 ...
 $ Trail       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Cascadas","Limones",..: 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ No.Specimens: int  1 0 2 2 3 4 5 0 1 1 ...
 $ Trap        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Net","Pan": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

And here is the complete data.set (these are only my preliminary analyses)

```
           Date Trap.No Altitude    Trail No.Specimens Trap
1   28-Aug-2014      W2     1558 Cascadas            1  Pan
2   28-Aug-2014      W5     1635 Cascadas            0  Pan
3   28-Aug-2014      W8     1703 Cascadas            2  Pan
4   28-Aug-2014     W11     1771 Cascadas            2  Pan
5   28-Aug-2014     W14     1840 Cascadas            3  Pan
6   28-Aug-2014     W17     1929    Tower            4  Pan
7   28-Aug-2014     W20     1990    Tower            5  Pan
8   28-Aug-2014     W23     2047    Tower            0  Pan
9   28-Aug-2014     W26     2112    Tower            1  Pan
10  28-Aug-2014     W29     2193    Tower            1  Pan
11  28-Aug-2014     W32     2255    Tower            0  Pan
12  30-Aug-2014      N1     1562 Cascadas            5  Net
13  30-Aug-2014      N2     1635 Cascadas            0  Net
14  30-Aug-2014      N3     1723 Cascadas            2  Net
15  30-Aug-2014      N4     1779 Cascadas            0  Net
16  30-Aug-2014      N5     1842 Cascadas            3  Net
17  30-Aug-2014      N6     1924    Tower            2  Net
18  30-Aug-2014      N7     1979    Tower            2  Net
19  30-Aug-2014      N8     2046    Tower            0  Net
20  30-Aug-2014      N9     2110    Tower            0  Net
21  30-Aug-2014     N10     2185    Tower            0  Net
22  30-Aug-2014     N11     2241    Tower            0  Net
23  31-Aug-2014      N1     1562 Cascadas            1  Net
24  31-Aug-2014      N2     1635 Cascadas            1  Net
25  31-Aug-2014      N3     1723 Cascadas            0  Net
26  31-Aug-2014      N4     1779 Cascadas            0  Net
27  31-Aug-2014      N5     1842 Cascadas            0  Net
28  31-Aug-2014      N6     1924    Tower            0  Net
29  31-Aug-2014      N7     1979    Tower            7  Net
30  31-Aug-2014      N8     2046    Tower            4  Net
31  31-Aug-2014      N9     2110    Tower            6  Net
32  31-Aug-2014     N10     2185    Tower            1  Net
33  31-Aug-2014     N11     2241    Tower            1  Net
34  01-Sep-2014      W1     1539 Cascadas            0  Pan
35  01-Sep-2014      W2     1558 Cascadas            0  Pan
36  01-Sep-2014      W3     1585 Cascadas            2  Pan
37  01-Sep-2014      W4     1604 Cascadas            0  Pan
38  01-Sep-2014      W5     1623 Cascadas            1  Pan
39  01-Sep-2014      W6     1666 Cascadas            4  Pan
40  01-Sep-2014      W7     1699 Cascadas            0  Pan
41  01-Sep-2014      W8     1703 Cascadas            0  Pan
42  01-Sep-2014      W9     1746 Cascadas            1  Pan
43  01-Sep-2014     W10     1762 Cascadas            0  Pan
44  01-Sep-2014     W11     1771 Cascadas            0  Pan
45  01-Sep-2014     W12     1796 Cascadas            1  Pan
46  01-Sep-2014     W13     1825 Cascadas            0  Pan
47  01-Sep-2014     W14     1840    Tower            4  Pan
48  01-Sep-2014     W15     1859    Tower            2  Pan
49  01-Sep-2014     W16     1889    Tower            2  Pan
50  01-Sep-2014     W17     1929    Tower            0  Pan
51  01-Sep-2014     W18     1956    Tower            0  Pan
52  01-Sep-2014     W19     1990    Tower            1  Pan
53  01-Sep-2014     W20     2002    Tower            3  Pan
54  01-Sep-2014     W21     2023    Tower            2  Pan
55  01-Sep-2014     W22     2047    Tower            0  Pan
56  01-Sep-2014     W23     2068    Tower            1  Pan
57  01-Sep-2014     W24     2084    Tower            0  Pan
58  01-Sep-2014     W25     2112    Tower            1  Pan
59  01-Sep-2014     W26     2136    Tower            0  Pan
60  01-Sep-2014     W27     2150    Tower            1  Pan
61  01-Sep-2014     W28     2193    Tower            1  Pan
62  01-Sep-2014     W29     2219    Tower            0  Pan
63  01-Sep-2014     W30     2227    Tower            1  Pan
64  01-Sep-2014     W31     2255    Tower            0  Pan
85   03/06/2015    WT47     1901    Tower            2  Pan
86   03/06/2015    WT48     1938    Tower            2  Pan
87   03/06/2015    WT49     1963    Tower            2  Pan
88   03/06/2015    WT50     1986    Tower            0  Pan
89   03/06/2015    WT51     2012    Tower            9  Pan
90   03/06/2015    WT52     2033    Tower            0  Pan
91   03/06/2015    WT53     2050    Tower            4  Pan
92   03/06/2015    WT54     2081    Tower            2  Pan
93   03/06/2015    WT55     2107    Tower            1  Pan
94   03/06/2015    WT56     2128    Tower            4  Pan
95   03/06/2015    WT57     2155    Tower            0  Pan
96   03/06/2015    WT58     2179    Tower            2  Pan
97   03/06/2015    WT59     2214    Tower            0  Pan
98   03/06/2015    WT60     2233    Tower            0  Pan
99   03/06/2015    WT61     2261    Tower            0  Pan
100  03/06/2015    WT62     2278    Tower            0  Pan
101  03/06/2015    WT63     2300    Tower            0  Pan
102  04/06/2015    WT31     1497 Cascadas            0  Pan
103  04/06/2015    WT32     1544 Cascadas            1  Pan
104  04/06/2015    WT33     1568 Cascadas            1  Pan
105  04/06/2015    WT34     1574 Cascadas            0  Pan
106  04/06/2015    WT35     1608 Cascadas            5  Pan
107  04/06/2015    WT36     1630 Cascadas            3  Pan
108  04/06/2015    WT37     1642 Cascadas            0  Pan
109  04/06/2015    WT38     1672 Cascadas            5  Pan
110  04/06/2015    WT39     1685 Cascadas            6  Pan
111  04/06/2015    WT40     1723 Cascadas            3  Pan
112  04/06/2015    WT41     1744 Cascadas            2  Pan
113  04/06/2015    WT42     1781 Cascadas            1  Pan
114  04/06/2015    WT43     1794 Cascadas            2  Pan
115  04/06/2015    WT44     1833 Cascadas            0  Pan
116  04/06/2015    WT45     1855 Cascadas            4  Pan
117  04/06/2015    WT46     1876 Cascadas            2  Pan
```

Comment: Can you post `str()` of your data or ideally, simulate a reproducible example?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are actually passing to the function. Normally you don't pass `data=` as a character value, it probably should be `data=Santa.Lucia` rather than `data="Santa.Lucia"`.

Comment: @BondedDust. Fantastic! This works and my model seems to run now. Could you explain the orthogonal polynomial poly(Altitude,2) so I can understand the model outcome? Also how can I compare this model with a model without the quadratic term using this function. Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  As @BondedDust suggests, it's not practical
to use a two-level factor (`Trap`) as a random effect; in fact,
it doesn't seem right in principle either (the levels of `Trap` are
not arbitrary/randomly chosen/exchangeable).  When I tried a model
with quadratic altitude, fixed effect of trap, and random effect
of `Date`, I was warned that I might want to rescale a parameter:

```
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

(you saw this warning mixed in with your error messages). The only continuous (and hence worth rescaling) predictor is `Altitude`, so I centered and scaled it with `scale()` (the only disadvantage is that this changes the quantitative interpretation of the coefficients, but the model itself is practically identical).  I also added an observation-level random effect to allow for overdispersion.

The results seem OK, and agree with the picture.

```
library(lme4)
Santa.Lucia <- transform(Santa.Lucia,
                         scAlt=scale(Altitude),
                         obs=factor(seq(nrow(Santa.Lucia))))
model7 <- glmer(No.Specimens~scAlt+I(scAlt^2)+Trap+(1|Date)+(1|obs),
                family="poisson",data=Santa.Lucia,na.action=na.omit)

summary(model7)

## Random effects:
##  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  obs    (Intercept) 0.64712  0.8044  
##  Date   (Intercept) 0.02029  0.1425  
## Number of obs: 97, groups:  obs, 97; Date, 6
## 
## Fixed effects:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
## (Intercept)  0.53166    0.31556   1.685  0.09202 . 
## scAlt       -0.22867    0.14898  -1.535  0.12480   
## I(scAlt^2)  -0.52840    0.16355  -3.231  0.00123 **
## TrapPan     -0.01853    0.32487  -0.057  0.95451
```

Test the quadratic term by comparing with a model that lacks it ...

```
model7R <- update(model7, . ~ . - I(scAlt^2))
## convergence warning, but probably OK ...
anova(model7,model7R)
```

On principle it might be worth looking at the interaction between the quadratic altitude model and Trap (allowing for different altitude trends by trap type), but the picture suggests it won't do much ...

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(Santa.Lucia,aes(Altitude,No.Specimens,colour=Trap))+
    stat_sum(aes(size=factor(..n..)))+
        scale_size_discrete(range=c(2,4))+
            geom_line(aes(group=Date),colour="gray",alpha=0.3)+
                geom_smooth(method="gam",family="quasipoisson",
                            formula=y~poly(x,2))+
                    geom_smooth(method="gam",family="quasipoisson",
                                formula=y~poly(x,2),se=FALSE,
                                aes(group=1),colour="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost surely due to you passing a character vector to the `data` argument:

```
..., data="Santa.Lucia, ..."
```

`?glmer` says the `data` argument should be:

```
data: an optional data frame containing the variables named in
      ‘formula’.  By default the variables are taken from the
      environment from which ‘lmer’ is called. While ‘data’ is
      optional, the package authors _strongly_ recommend its use,
      especially when later applying methods such as ‘update’ and
      ‘drop1’ to the fitted model (_such methods are not guaranteed
      to work properly if ‘data’ is omitted_). If ‘data’ is
      omitted, variables will be taken from the environment of
      ‘formula’ (if specified as a formula) or from the parent
      frame (if specified as a character vector).
```

The last part in parentheses, *"if specified as a character vector"* relates to what happens if the specification of `formula` is as a character vector, not to specifying `data` as a character.

Correct your call to include `data = Santa.Lucia` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks so much. Such a silly mistake I never realized I was making. Unfortunately I now have new error messages which are even more indecipherable. I have edited my original question to include them. Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You've managed to use two different formats for Date. Here's a fix:

```
Santa.Lucia$Date2 <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(Santa.Lucia$Date)) > 10,  
                             as.Date(Santa.Lucia$Date, format="%d-%b-%Y"), 
                             as.Date(Santa.Lucia$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y") )
```

I tried a simpler model:

```
( model6 <-glmer(No.Specimens~Altitude+(1|Date2)+(1|Trap),family="poisson",data=Santa.Lucia,na.action=na.omit) )
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
glmerMod]
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: No.Specimens ~ Altitude + (1 | Date2) + (1 | Trap)
   Data: Santa.Lucia
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 368.6522  378.9510 -180.3261  360.6522        93 
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 Date2  (Intercept) 0.2248  
 Trap   (Intercept) 0.0000  
Number of obs: 97, groups:  Date2, 6; Trap, 2
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)     Altitude  
  1.3696125   -0.0004992  
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0516296 (tol = 0.001, component 3)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I'm actually able to get my suggested modification to run without error or warning but I think that using those two groupings is not right because one predicts the other:

```
> table(Santa.Lucia$Date2, Santa.Lucia$Trap)

        Net Pan
  16310   0  11
  16312  11   0
  16313  11   0
  16314   0  31
  16589   0  17
  16590   0  16
```

That's why you are getting non-convergence. It's not the error model that is at fault, but the pathology in your design and data collection. I question whether you really have sufficient data to support a mixed model:

```
( model5 <-glm(No.Specimens~Altitude,family="poisson",data=Santa.Lucia,na.action=na.omit) )

Call:  glm(formula = No.Specimens ~ Altitude, family = "poisson", data = Santa.Lucia, 
    na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     Altitude  
  1.4218234   -0.0005391  

Degrees of Freedom: 96 Total (i.e. Null);  95 Residual
Null Deviance:      215.3 
Residual Deviance: 213.2    AIC: 368.6
```

To compare with a quadratic altitude model:

```
( model5.2 <-glm(No.Specimens~poly(Altitude,2),family="poisson",data=Santa.Lucia,na.action=na.omit) )

Call:  glm(formula = No.Specimens ~ poly(Altitude, 2), family = "poisson", 
    data = Santa.Lucia, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)  poly(Altitude, 2)1  poly(Altitude, 2)2  
            0.3188             -1.7116             -3.9539  

Degrees of Freedom: 96 Total (i.e. Null);  94 Residual
Null Deviance:      215.3 
Residual Deviance: 194.6    AIC: 352
> anova(model5.2)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: poisson, link: log

Response: No.Specimens

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


                  Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                                 96     215.31
poly(Altitude, 2)  2   20.698        94     194.61
> anova(model5.2, model5)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: No.Specimens ~ poly(Altitude, 2)
Model 2: No.Specimens ~ Altitude
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance
1        94     194.61            
2        95     213.20 -1   -18.59
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Would it be okay then to only include Trap-type as a random effect in this model? Thanks again

Comment: I've been advised by experts in this area that using mixed models when you only have two groups really is not useful. You don't get a stable estimate of the variance with the grouping variable. It's really no different than simply adding a covariate in a full fixed-effects model. So "yes" to examining the possible effect of trap type, but "no" to mixed-model. The anova "significance" is basically the same.